# "deeper" understanding of complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a project regarding complex analysis regarding several complex variables in my math class and for the complex differentiability of a function $f(z)$ in $\mathbb C$ I used the definition from https://www.jirka.org/scv/scv.pdf. Here, the definition is in regard to holomorphic functions, but the main point is that a function $f: U \to \mathbb C$, where $U \subset \mathbb C$, is complex differentiable, if the limit $$ \lim_{\zeta \in \mathbb C \to 0} \frac{f(z+\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta} $$ for all $z \in U$ exists. Then we have $
f'(z) = \lim_{\zeta \in \mathbb C \to 0} \frac{f(z+\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta}$. However, my professor wasn't satisfied with this, meaning that it won't work like that.

I tried to expand on this by explaining that if we look at the complex plane $\mathbb C$, we immediately see that, given a point $z \in \mathbb C$, it can be approached from infinitely many directions in more than one way. This directly includes that, while approaching $z$, one can take the limit along both the real and the imaginary axis. This means that $f^{'}(z)$, as defined above, follows from a two-dimensional limit. And it is the case that only if both limits are the same, i.e. it is independet if we take the limit along the real or the imaginary axis, that we can say that a limit at the point $z$ exists, thus that $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z$.

Also, as far as I understand it, an analogous statement of the limits along the real and imaginary axis being equivalent is that the function $f(z)$, if composed like follows: $f(z = x + iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, satisfies the so called Cauchy-Riemann equations

\begin{equation} \label{eq:3}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{equation}

and thus is complex differentiable from which follows that it is also holomorphic.

It seems, however, that somehow I'm still missing the point.

Is there any deeper insight around complex differentiation that I'm missing or something that I don't understand the right way?

Comment: "it won't work like that?" That's a correct definition of differentiability

Comment: Though you're wrong to say that the function is differentiable if the directional derivatives along the real and imaginary axes exists. You're wrong even if you look at directional derivatives along all possible rays (there are, I believe, counterexamples in the calculus of $\Bbb R^2$)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have asked him but I he meant I should again read the chapter in the script

Comment: @FShrike I meant that if the limits coincide, i.e. independent from which direction the limit is taken, if it goes to the same $z$, the function is differentiable. Isn't this correct?

Comment: @syphracos If you restrict to "direction" meaning: *along a ray*, as you seemed to be doing, then that's wrong. It's correct if you remove absolutely all restrictions on the 'direction'

Comment: @FShrike that's what I meant with independent from direction. Maybe a better explanation would be that the limit must be the same for all the infinite possible directions which one can take. Would this be correct?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez regarding the script, in the section about holomorphic functions he mentions also that a function cannot depend on $z$ and $z*$ simultaneously as this would violate the C-R equations and that, if the component functions $u(x,y), v(x,y)$, if they are twice continuously differentiable, it follows from the C-R equations that $u$ and $v$ satisfy the partial differential equations of Laplace, thus that every holomorphic function only differ by harmonic functions. and then he goes to combinations of holomorphic functions and the radius of convergence

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez do You have an idea in which context the above deffinition of complex differentiability wouldn't hold ?

Comment: @syphracos It's liable for misinterpretation. Better to say: "*the limit exists*". Anyone who knows the topology of $\Bbb C$ then knows exactly what is meant

Comment: It's really unclear what more your teacher would want? Maybe you were supposed to talk about how holomorphic functions are analytic, in contrast with real-differentiable and real-analytic functions? It's hard to tell what he'd have in mind.

Comment: @BrunoB I talk about analyticity a little bit later when going to analytic continuation and mentione, of course, that holomorphic functions are analytic.
as to what he had in his mind, yeah, it's hard to tell but i think it's something like "for a better grade, find out".. hence my question here as if i somehow missed something

Comment: Could he mean "$f'(z)$ is the complex number $A$ such that $f(w)=f(z)+A(w-z)+o(|w-z|)$ holds"? This is exactly the same as your first definition but written differently.

Comment: @trisct It's really hard to tell.. Not sure at all